# Razor Views with same relative path within class libraries are picked up wrongly

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a project which consists of a ASP.NET Core MVC project and two Razor Class Library projects being referenced by the MVC project.

Everything works fine with regard to Controllers and Views.

However, if two Views have the same relative path (e.g. `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`, it happens that the View from the wrong library gets picked up and rendered.

How can this be avoided (aside from having a unique relative path)?

Comment: When you say the "wrong library gets picked", what is your expectation regarding what is "right"? MVC uses a "nearest wins" approach when performing [view discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#view-discovery), so a view in the application project will win over a view with a matching name/path in a referenced library, but if multiple views with the same path have equal distance from the app, how would you expect it to disambiguate? You can customize the logic with a custom `IViewLocationExpander` in the app.

Comment: Given I have to libraries `Sales` and ``CRM` my expectation would have been that Controllers and Tag Helpers from `Sales` would pick up views from `Sales` library and Controllers and Tag Helpers from `CRM` would pick up views from `CRM` library. I'm already using `IViewLocationExpander` in both libraries but if I apply the same folder/file naming rules I'm ending up with the same problem. I wonder if I could weave in some Assembly name or the like.

Comment: @DamianEdwards I'm aware that this is a somewhat theoretical issue but things often break where nobody expects them to because "this is a non issue".

Comment: For the Identity UI views this is achieved using areas, such that the class library for ASP.NET Core Identity UI resolves views in an area called "Identity", e.g. `/Areas/Identity/Account/Login`. The app can still override a given view by placing a view file in matching area path locally.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#areas-for-controllers-with-views

Comment: Ah yes, I totally forgot about Areas. Will give it a try - thanks!